# Testing if Rust string is contained in an array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, rust, contains

I'm a Rust beginner and I'm trying to extend a condition that currently tests a string for equality to another string literal, so that the test is now whether the string is contained in an array of string literals.

In Python, I would just write `string_to_test in ['foo','bar']`. How can I port this to rust?

Here's my attempt, but this doesn't compile:

```rust
fn main() {
  let test_string = "foo";
  ["foo", "bar"].iter().any(|s| s == test_string);
}
```

with errors:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: can't compare `&str` with `str`
 --> src/main.rs:3:35
  |
3 |   ["foo", "bar"].iter().any(|s| s == test_string);
  |                                   ^^ no implementation for `&str == str`
  |
  = help: the trait `PartialEq<str>` is not implemented for `&str`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `PartialEq<&str>` for `&&str`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

I can't figure this out unfortunately and couldn't find a similar question on StackOverflow or forums.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Herohtar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/574531/herohtar) suggested the general solution:

```rust
["foo", "bar"].contains(&test_string)
```

[PitaJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/847382/pitaj) suggested this terse macro in a comment, this works only with tokens known at compile time as [Finomnis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2902833/finomnis) noted in a comment:

```rust
matches!(test_string, "foo" | "bar")
```

This is how I got my code to work:

```rust
["foo", "bar"].iter().any(|&s| s == test_string);
```

Comment: `["foo", "bar"].contains(&test_string)` is also perfectly fine.

Comment: this is a more general solution in that the closure can use any code that returns a boolean, e.g., `ends_with(s)`, etc.